# How does Anaconda handle existing Python installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I am relatively new to Python and to Ubuntu. I have had problems in the past handling multiple versions of Python on my computer so I wanted to install Anaconda to use a Python version in a separate environment.

However, I am having trouble understanding how Anaconda handles multiple Python versions. I apologize for the lengthily post but I am desperate to understand this. To give some context, here is what I did:

**Step 1: checking for existing Python versions**

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 freshly installed.

```
$ cd
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*

# Output:
#    0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25 12:11 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
# 4420 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 Oct 22 12:32 /usr/bin/python3.6
# 4420 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 Oct 22 12:32 /usr/bin/python3.6m
#    0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25 12:11 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
```

So far so good, I basically have 3.6 installed by default.

**Step 2: installating Anaconda**

I wanted to keep things simple so decided to download Anaconda that comes with Python 3.7 at this link:
https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

I did so by following these exact instructions:
http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

This included:

- Pressed Enter and typed "yes" to view and accept licensing (points 4. and 5. in instructions)
- Entered "Enter" to accept default location (point 6. in instructions)
- Entered "yes" to allow installer to prepend Anaconda to PATH
- Entered "yes" to allow installation of MicrosoftVS

All this worked. I can launch Anaconda by typing "anaconda-navigator" in terminal and upon launching Spyder, I can see I have version 3.7

**Step3: checking existing Python versions (again)**

Here, I just wanted to understand where everything was stored.

```
$ cd
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*

# Output
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
# -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3670448 Nov 12 14:31 /usr/bin/python2.7
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25 12:11 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
# -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 Oct 22 12:32 /usr/bin/python3.6
# -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4522328 Oct 22 12:32 /usr/bin/python3.6m
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25 12:11 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
```

**This brings to my questions (which are all linked)**

- **What happened? Why is Python 2.7 here?? Does Anaconda need 2.7 to run or something? Indeed, a bit of searching in the (long) output of the Anaconda installation revealed:**

*mono-runtime-sgen po-debconf python python-minimal python2.7
python2.7-minimal x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
m4-doc libmail-box-perl python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc
python2.7 python2.7-minimal x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-minimal.
 Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1) ...t*

- **Where is 3.7? Is it in /home/anaconda3?**
- **Why are the symbolic links in the output of "ls -l /usr/bin/python*" wrong? Indeed, when I open a terminal:**

  - "python" points to 3.7, not 2.7 as suggested
  - "python3" points to 3.7, not 3.6 as suggested
  - "python2" points to "2.7.15rc1"

Am I missing something or is this all normal? Apologies for the long post. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda in installed in `~/anaconda2` or `~/anaconda3` by default except if you specified another directory. Normally, anaconda does not change anything in `/usr/bin` but it adds `/path/to/anaconda/bin` to your path (in `~/.bashrc`) (again, you have to specify this at installation). You can check using `which -a python` to see what python executable are in your path, the first result being the one that will be executed when you call `python` from command line.

**NB**: You can download anaconda installation script with python2.7 or 3.7 but only one version of python will be included by default. You can download two versions but make sure to only add one of them in your path if you do

For the symlinks, I cannot help you as I don't use Ubuntu. What I can tell you though is that my system links `python` to `python2.7` but maybe that Ubuntu changed this in its latest release.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me realise that indeed, the reason for my confusion is that my $PATH now looks like so: /home/user-name/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin, meaning that my "Anaconda Python" takes "priority" over the ones in /usr/bin and hence that the "python" and "python3" both call the "Anaconda Python", not the ones in /usr/bin. And from what I understand, Python2.7 was installed in usr/bin by the installer when I accepted to install Microsoft VS.

Comment: Yes, anaconda takes precedence over the other folders. If you suspect conflicts, then remove the anaconda-related lines in `.bashrc` (I've had problems in the past, so I prefer to tweak this myself now). And it is possible that VS Code install some unexpected stuff, although I'm surprised python2.7 did not come with Ubuntu 18.04. As far as I know, they only planned to switch to python3 in the next release.

Comment: I don't think they are any conflicts, I was just confused but now that I understand the order of the $PATH, it makes sense why the simlinks in /usr/bin looked "wrong". They are not wrong, its just that /home/user-name/anaconda3/bin takes priority over anything in /usr/bin. I was also surprised by the fact Python 2.7 is not installed by default (I only very recently switched to Ubuntu 18.04) but this link confirmed this was the case: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes